# Splitting m Argument in a Starred Command

Tags: starred-version, splitargument

I have been trying to use `\SplitArgument` onto a command with also contains an *s*-type argument. I have tried everything, but the star is not taken into account, and on top of that, I get a parasitic space. Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

In the **MWE**, the star variant should remove the automatic initial space.

The AUX command works flawlessly, but I can't split my argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[citestyle=ext-authoryear-comp]{biblatex}



\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{labelname:poss}{#1's}

\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthand:poss}{%
    \ifnameundef{labelname}{#1's}{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle:poss}{\mkbibemph{#1}'s}

\DeclareFieldFormat{label:poss}{#1's}


\newrobustcmd*{\posscitealias}{%
    \AtNextCite{%
        \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{labelname}{labelname:poss}%
        \DeclareFieldAlias{shorthand}{shorthand:poss}%
        \DeclareFieldAlias{citetitle}{citetitle:poss}%
        \DeclareFieldAlias{label}{label:poss}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\tcitepos}{%
    \posscitealias%
    \textcite}



\NewDocumentCommand{\tcitecomAUX}{smm}{%
    \IfBooleanF{#1}{\space}%
    \textcite{#2}\space and\space\tcitepos{#3}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tcitecom}{s>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m}{\tcitecomAUX#2{#1}}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    
    @book{smi96,
        author = {Smith, Adam},
        year = {1996},
        title = {Economy},
        publisher = {My company} 
    }
    
    @book{joh84,
        author = {Jones, Indiana},
        year = {1984},
        title = {The Graal},
        publisher = {My company} 
    }
    
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
    
    As in\tcitecomAUX{smi96}{joh84} common theory...
    
    As in\tcitecomAUX*{smi96}{joh84} common theory... % Works nicely.
    
    \vspace{2ex}
    
    As in\tcitecom{smi96,joh84} common theory... % Extra space.
    
    As in\tcitecom*{smi96,joh84} common theory... % The star is ignored.
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the wrong arguments (and don't get *that* output).

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{smi96,
        author = {Smith, Adam},
        year = {1996},
        title = {Economy},
        publisher = {My company} 
    }
    @book{joh84,
        author = {Jones, Indiana},
        year = {1984},
        title = {The Graal},
        publisher = {My company} 
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[citestyle=ext-authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{labelname:poss}{#1's}

\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthand:poss}{%
    \ifnameundef{labelname}{#1's}{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle:poss}{\mkbibemph{#1}'s}

\DeclareFieldFormat{label:poss}{#1's}


\newrobustcmd*{\posscitealias}{%
    \AtNextCite{%
        \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{labelname}{labelname:poss}%
        \DeclareFieldAlias{shorthand}{shorthand:poss}%
        \DeclareFieldAlias{citetitle}{citetitle:poss}%
        \DeclareFieldAlias{label}{label:poss}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\tcitepos}{%
    \posscitealias%
    \textcite}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tcitecomAUX}{mmm}{%
  #1\textcite{#2} and \tcitepos{#3}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tcitecom}{s>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\tcitecomAUX{}#2}{\tcitecomAUX{ }#2}%
}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
    
As in\tcitecom{smi96,joh84} common theory... % Extra space.
    
As in\tcitecom*{smi96,joh84} common theory... % The star is ignored.
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help (I confess, this is *very* hard for me to understand, I have to think it through).

Comment: @VincentKrebs The auxiliary function should never have “special” argument types: you have already sorted them out with the main function.

Comment: I see. I wouldn't have thought of passing the presence vs. absence of the space as a classic-type first argument for the AUX command. This is kind of tricky, I believe my question is not that trivial and will help other beginners.

Comment: I was wondering, is the auxiliary function only a convenience to divide the code and avoid mistakes, or is it mandatory?

Comment: @VincentKrebs When using argument processors, it’s mandatory.

Comment: I thought so (didn't find an alternative way to pass the `#n`).